# How to add an Event object to Unity's EventSystem

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I have an event from `Event.current` and I want to 'replay' it by making the event system process it again, how do I do that? Can I access the scripts responsible for raising events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be able to track down how events are created using IL Spy then use reflection to invoke that, but unfortunately there is no public API for creating events manually.

Comment: Unity UI sub system is open source, so no need for IL, however I would agree on the assesment that manually creating the events can be a major pain

Answer (score 0):

I found a neat C# library which simulates input called [Windows Input Simulator](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator) which does a good job of raising all the keyboard events I needed. Looks like it also works for things like mouse input!